# Shouldn't billing address and payment be combined?

Tags: e-commerce, user-centered-design

Currently designing an e-commerce website and doing a lot of competitor analysis.

One question that bothers me is why most websites combine shipping and billing information? Most importantly, even if they offer Paypal as a payment method.

It's usually 3 steps: **Shipping & Billing > Payment > Confirmation**
I understand that billing information is important for an easier transaction when using Credit Card as a payment method (Address Verification System). But is it necessary if I use other payment methods? Should it not be combined with Payment (only when Credit Card payment is selected)? Maybe there are some other reasons I'm not seeing, but this really confuses me even as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a good point.

Most large e-commerce sites already only ask for Billing address when credit card is selected, along with option to check off "Same as Shipping".

This is the case with Amazon, Walmart, Samsung, Best Buy, Newegg, etc.  So you may want to expand scope of your competitor analysis.

However, it's not completely unacceptable to use Shipping and Billing on same page as long as payment information was asked *beforehand*, so that the page can conditionally hide Billing section if CC wasn't selected.